# MySQL - How to select rows until condition is met

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a numeric field (call it NUM), I want to select rows until the sum of all NUM selected reaches some threshold. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(  x int not null primary key 
,  y int not null );

INSERT INTO t(x,y)
VALUES (1, 1)
  ,(2, 1)
  ,(3, 2)
  ,(4, 8)
  ,(5, 3)
  ,(6, 5)
  ,(7, 4);
```

You can determine the cumulative sum like below, and then filter the result in an outer select:

```
select x,y,acc 
from (
    select x, y, (select sum(y) 
                  from T T2 
                  where T2.x <= T1.x) as acc 
    from T T1
) as tmp 
where acc < 10;

+---+---+------+
| x | y | acc  |
+---+---+------+
| 1 | 1 |    1 |
| 2 | 1 |    2 |
| 3 | 2 |    4 |
+---+---+------+
```

For DBMS that support window functions like sum(..) over ( ... ) much more elegant solutions exists. The above corresponds to:

```
select x,y,acc
from (
    select x, y, sum(y) over (order by x) as acc 
    from t
) tt
where acc < 10;
```

A [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54c347ecefec9891394a6b36be372889) for MySQL 8

Comment: where can i get more informatino about using "sum(...) and over(...)" elegantly to solve this? I have an almost identical problem in bigquery

Comment: @frogeyedpeas, try: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts as a start

Comment: I updated the answer with an example